# Serve Angular PWA via ngrok gives Invalid WebSocket Frame Error

Tags: angular, websocket, progressive-web-apps, ngrok

When I start up an Angular PWA Project and try to access it via ngrok, I always get the following errors:

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear
    at Receiver.getInfo (/Users/efkah/Repositories/GitHub/pwa-example/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:189:14)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/Users/efkah/Repositories/GitHub/pwa-example/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:136:22)
    at Receiver._write (/Users/efkah/Repositories/GitHub/pwa-example/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:83:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.socketOnData (/Users/efkah/Repositories/GitHub/pwa-example/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1116:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at Receiver.receiverOnError (/Users/efkah/Repositories/GitHub/pwa-example/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1002:13)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'WS_ERR_UNEXPECTED_RSV_1',
  [Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
}
(base) FAIL: 1
```

ngrok output:

```
GET /ws                        502 Bad Gateway                                                                                                      
GET /ws                        101 Switching Protocols                                                                                              
GET /main.js                   200 OK                                                                                                               
GET /styles.js                 200 OK    
GET [everything else]          200 OK
```

Reproduce:

```
ng new example
cd example
ng add @angular/pwa
npm i ngrok
```

now open 2 terminals and run `npm start` and `npx ngrok http --host-header=rewrite --region=eu 4200` - then open the pwa via the ngrok link - you will get the crash.

I am unable to make something of the error, any help is appreciated.

Update: Interesting enough, if I access ws://xxx.eu.ngrok.io instead of http or https the server doesn't crash, so the problem seems to be correlated to the "Switching Protocols" part of the ngrok output

Answer (score 0):

Thank you stackoverflow rubberduck ;-)
I suspected a problem with the angular dev-server, and after doing a full roundtrip with serving on nginx, i found the answer was hidden in the angular docs:

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server

> Because ng serve does not work with service workers, you must use a separate HTTP server to test your project locally.

So basically, it is known to not work.